# How to get Grunt Watch to send notification on OSX Yosemite

Tags: gruntjs, less

I'm trying to get Grunt Watch to send me notification windows on OSX Yosemite when it it reloads a file (I'm using it to watch for CSS changes and compile them into LESS file). How do I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify

Comment: @MikeDriver thanks that seems like the right way to go!

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeDriver pointed out, this is the correct way to go:
github.com/dylang/grunt-notify